ADO query for test case- suite filtering
Can we write a query in ADO to filter out test cases based on certain field from a specific test suite based on suite name/ID?
If not is it possible to fetch the test cases with certain field applied from a test suite using API request?
Also can we use the API response (ex: list of test cases) to pivot a chart in ADO?

Hi GunacelanM, Have you got a chance to test the suggested API in my answer below and may I know if this is the API that you need? Hope the information may help resolve your issue. Thx and have a nice weekend.

I can get all the test cases from a specific suite. But I want to add specific field to filter test cases say suppose automationstatus field or priority field..How to acheive that?

So you would expect to get the test cases from a specific test suite and then from the API results, filter out the test cases by priority or automation status field of those test cases right? Please correct me if there is any misunderstanding.

Absolutely right

Hi @GunacelanM, I have update the answer according to our discussions. Hope it helps resolve your query. Please let us know if it works for you. Thx.

Hi @GunacelanM, May I know the latest status of the issue and if the updated answer below to filter the test cases of a test suite by priority and automation status fields can help resolve your query in this ticket? Appreciate your time and sharing.

Update
Based on the further discussions, here are the requirements so far:

To get the test cases from a specific test suite; for which, we can use this API to Get Test Suites - Test Cases;
To filter out the expected test cases from above response by the fields of priority and Automation status; for which, we can use this API to Query By Wiql.

Here is a sample PowerShell script for your reference.
$organization = "AzureDevOpsOrgName"
$project = "TheProjectName"
$MyPat = 'xxxxxx'
$B64Pat = [Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes(":$MyPat"))
$headers = @{
    'Authorization' = 'Basic ' + "$B64Pat"
    'Content-Type' = 'application/json'
}

$testcasesURL = "https://dev.azure.com/$organization/$project/_apis/test/Plans/836/suites/839/testcases?api-version=5.0"
$testcases = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri $testcasesURL -Headers $headers

$testCaseId = $testcases.value | ForEach-Object { $_.testCase.id }
$testCaseIds= $testCaseId -join ","
$testCaseIds

$queryURL = "https://dev.azure.com/$organization/_apis/wit/wiql?api-version=7.1-preview.2"
$queryBody = @"
{
  "query": "Select [System.Id], [System.Title], [System.State] From WorkItems Where [System.Id] in ($testCaseIds) and [Microsoft.VSTS.Common.Priority] = 1 and [Microsoft.VSTS.TCM.AutomationStatus] = 'Not Automated'"
}
"@
$queryResult = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri $queryURL -Headers $headers -Body $queryBody



In Azure Boards, I don't see how a Test Case can be reflected in any filed of a Test Suite. If you requirement is to get to know the Test Cases added in a Test Suite in Test Plans, you may use this API
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/test/Plans/{planId}/suites/{suiteId}/testcases?api-version=5.0



I can get all the test cases from a specific suite. But I want to add specific field to filter test cases say suppose automationstatus field or priority field..How to acheive that?
